# Adding custom headers to STOMP CONNECTED frame with Spring

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-messaging

Is it possible to add a custom header to the STOMP `CONNECTED` frame in Spring?

From what I have found in `StompSubProtocolHandler`, a `CONNECT_ACK` SiMP message gets converted to a `CONNECTED` STOMP message without retaining any header. So if a `ChannelInterceptor.preSend()` adds a custom header to the `CONNECT_ACK` message, that header won't be sent (in the `CONNECTED` message).

Is there any reason why it is like this? Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STOMP protocol doesn't allow arbitrary, user-defined headers in the [`CONNECTED` frame](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECTED_Frame). Only the `SEND`, `MESSAGE`, and `ERROR` frames support arbitrary headers. The `CONNECTED` frame supports the following headers in addition to the [standard headers](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Standard_Headers):

- Required

  - `version`
- Optional

  - `session`
  - `server`
  - `heart-beat`

See the [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Frames_and_Headers) for more details.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if I agree with the changes (edits) you made to this question (`CONNECTED` -> `CONNECT`). The `CONNECT` frame is the one sent by the client to the server while the `CONNECTED` one is sent by the server to the client (https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECTED_Frame). In my case, I wanted to add a header in the one sent by the server to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I rolled back the changes.

Comment: @JustinBertram I know you have already answered but to be sure is this even possible to append some arbitrary headers with CONNECTED frame?

Comment: @amicngh, please ask a new question if your use-case is different than the one covered in this question. This question has already been answered.